# Large $k$ asymptotic of $\Pr(X=k)$ for a compound Poisson random variable $X$

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-distributions

Let $N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\mu)$, and let $X|N = \sum_{k=1}^N Y_k$, where $Y_k$ are iid non-negative integer-valued random variables. The distribution of $X$ is known as [compound Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution).

[Panjer's recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panjer_recursion) can be used to evaluate $p_k = \Pr(X=k)$ recursively, but is not very well suited for evaluation at large $k$. I am therefore seeking a way to approximate $p_k$ for large $k$.

Let the $\mathcal{P}_Y(t)$ be the probability generating function of $Y$, then $\mathcal{P}_Z(t) = \exp\left( \mu \left( \mathcal{P}_Y(t)-1 \right) \right)$, I am hoping an answer to my question can be found in terms of $\mathcal{P}_Y(t)$.

Thank you!